# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection parameter

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, indexing

I am getting this error while trying to disable the first radio button on the radiobutton list using the vb code:

```
RadioButtonList1.Items(0).Enabled = False
```

Here is the aspx code

```
  <td class="TDLR">
     <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlFollow"            DataTextField="FollowDesc" DataValueField="FollowID">
     </asp:RadioButtonList>
       <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlFollow" runat="server" 
       ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SampleConnectionString %>"
       SelectCommand="Select FollowID, FollowDesc FROM FollowUp WHERE FollowID > 30">
   </asp:SqlDataSource>
  </td>
```

Comment: The error indicates that you are trying to set the Enabled value prior to the RadioButtonList being populated. Verify that your select statement returns a value. Also, where are you setting the Enabled value?

Comment: Additionally, do you have `ViewState` turned on? That too will modify the flow a little.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry am a bit new to programing. I intend to disable the first radiobutton on the grid. any help pls.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Items.Count first:

**EDIT :** Try the code in `Page_PreRender` like below:

```
Protected Sub Page_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
    If RadioButtonList1.Items.Count > 0 Then
        RadioButtonList1.Items(0).Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the items.count but it returned not count. I believe its not seeing it as a list. I basicly want to disable the first radio button that is being populated on the grid. Any help pls

Comment: @user3199339 - I believe you are trying to disable it before it is created. Try to do it in Page_PreRender. Please see my edit.